# Show Factorial instead of Gamma in the result of RSolve

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, special-functions, difference-equations

Now I wanted to solve for a recurring function with `RSolve`. Here's how I tried:

```
RSolveValue[{a[n] == n*a[n - 1] - n!, a[0] == 2}, a[n], n]
(*2 Pochhammer[1, n] - n Pochhammer[1, n]*)
Simplify[%, Element[n, Integers]]
(* -(-2 + n) Pochhammer[1, n] *)
FunctionExpand[%]
(* -(-2 + n) n Gamma[n] *)
```

Actually the result should be $(2-n)n!$, but how can I simplify the result by assuming `n` be positive, so the result could look nicer.

Comment: `FullSimplify[n Gamma[n], Element[n, Integers] && n > 0]` does simplify to `n!`.

Comment: @Karsten, but `FullSimplify[n Gamma[n] (2 - n), n ∈ Integers && n > 0]` doesn't produce factorials, thus necessitating the use of `ComplexityFunction`.

Comment: @Karsten, why doesn't FullSimplify[ Gamma[n], Element[n, Integers] && n > 0] simplify to (n - 1)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can increase penalty for `Gamma` and `Pochhammer` headers:

```
simplify[expr_, n_] := 
  FullSimplify[expr, n ∈ Integers && n > 0, 
   ComplexityFunction -> ((LeafCount@# + 
        10 Count[#, _Gamma | _Pochhammer, {0, ∞}]) &)];

simplify[RSolveValue[{a[n] == n*a[n - 1] - n!, a[0] == 2}, a[n], n], n]
(* -(-2 + n) n (-1 + n)! *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this suits your needs or not, but if you are certain that the argument to `Gamma` is a non-negative integer, then just make the replacement manually

```
RSolveValue[{a[n] == n*a[n - 1] - n!, a[0] == 2}, a[n], n]
(* 2 Pochhammer[1, n] - n Pochhammer[1, n] *)

Simplify[%, Element[n, Integers]]
(* -(-2 + n) Pochhammer[1, n] *)

FunctionExpand[%]
(* -(-2 + n) n Gamma[n] *)

% /. n Gamma[n] -> Factorial[n]
(* -(-2 + n) n! *)
```

Comment: `n! == Pochhammer[1, n] == Gamma[n + 1] == n Gamma[n]`.

Comment: (face turns red)

Answer (score 2):

```
rsv = RSolveValue[{a[n] == n*a[n - 1] - n!, a[0] == 2}, a[n], n]
```

> ```
> 2 Pochhammer[1, n] - n Pochhammer[1, n]
> ```

```
Simplify`SimplifyGamma @ rsv
```

> ```
> 2 n! - n n!
> ```

```
Developer`GammaSimplify @ rsv
```

> ```
> 2 n! - n n!
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Does appending

```
/. Gamma -> (x |-> Factorial[x - 1]) // Simplify
```

work?

PS You may need to do previously:

```
$Assumptions = {n \[Element] Integers, n > 0};
```