# Series for Sin[x] with specific notation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

I'm trying to get mathematicas series function for `Sin[x]` to output a result that look like this:

$\sin x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2 n+1) !} x^{2 n+1}$

I referred to ybeltukov's answer and used his code. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71593/69835

```
Clear["Global`*"];
series[expr_, x_, x0_] := 
 Defer[expr = Sum[#, {n, 0, \[Infinity]}]] &[
  FullSimplify@
    SeriesCoefficient[expr, {x, x0, n}, 
     Assumptions -> {n >= 0}] (x - x0)^n]
series[Sin[x], x, 0]
```

> $\operatorname{Sin}[x]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{i i^{n}\left(-1+(-1)^{n}\right) x^{n}}{2 n !}$

However, the result contains some complex numbers.

How to get the result in real number form

$\sin x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2 n+1) !} x^{2 n+1}$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A slight modification

```
Clear["Global`*"];
series[expr_, x_, x0_] := Defer[expr = Sum[#, {n, 0, \[Infinity]}]] &[
FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[SeriesCoefficient[expr, {x, x0, 2 n + 1}]], 
Assumptions -> n >= 0 && n \[Element] Integers] (x - x0)^(2 n + 1)]
```

works for odd functions:

```
series[Sin[x], x, 0]
```

> $\sin (x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n x^{2 n+1}}{\Gamma (2 n+2)}$

Comment: Nice. Minor suggestion, you can add `ComplexityFunction -> ((LeafCount@# + 10 Count[#, _Gamma | _Pochhammer, {0, \[Infinity]}]) &)` in `FullSimplify` to take care of the `Gamma` --- see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100409/show-factorial-instead-of-gamma-in-the-result-of-rsolve)

Comment: @user64494 Great answer! Thank you!

Comment: @kcr Thank you! The expression is perfect after your slight modification.

Answer (score 4):

```
Entity["MathematicalFunction", "Sin"]["SeriesRepresentations"][[2]][
  x] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
% // Activate

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** For a cleaner display

```
Entity["MathematicalFunction", "Sin"]["SeriesRepresentations"][[2]][x] // 
  Activate[#, Except[Sum]] & // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This piece of code is great!